# Angular 1 - Failed to launch 'unsafe:data:image/svg+xml en boton para descargar imagen en base64

Tags: javascript, html5, angularjs

Estoy intentando permitir la descarga de un qrCode que recibo del back.
Lo logro renderizar perfectamente. Pero el botón que hice para descargarlo me da error.

```
<div ng-controller="qrcodeCtrlEventos as showCase" ng-init="ini()">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <legend style="display: flex; flex-direction: column;">QR CODE DE ACCESO<span style="color:blue; font-size: 14px;">{{ngDialogData.alumno.egresado}}</span></legend>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row" ng-if="!visual.wait">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <img src={{qrImage}} alt='QR Code' width='350' height='350'>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row" ng-if="!visual.wait">
    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <a class="btn btn-sm btn-default" href={{qrImage}} download="qrCode.jpg">
            Descargar
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Esta es la función en el archivo js

```
app.controller("qrcodeCtrlEventos", function($scope, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, ngDialog, $routeParams, $http, $location) {
$scope.ini = function() {
    $scope.visual = { wait: true, block: false, btn: 'Guardar', info: { visible: false } };

    $http({
        method: "POST",
        url: "eventos/qrcode/" + 1,
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.qrImage = JSON.parse(response.data)

        $scope.visual.wait = false;

    }, function myError(response) {
        alert('Se produjo un error por favor intentelo nuevamente.');
    });

}
```

});

El error es

> Failed to launch 'unsafe:data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHZlcnNpb249IjEuMSIgY2xhc3M9InFyLXN2ZyAiIHN0eWxlPSJ3aWR0aDogMTAwJTsgtM1ogIiAvPjwvc3ZnPg0K' because the scheme does not have a registered handler

Aclaro que soy junior jaja.
He googleado ya un par de horas y estoy perdido. Leí que podía ser que el hrf del "a" no empieza con http pero la ser una data/image en base64 nunca lo va a tener.
Quizás hay otra manera de lograr lo mismo.

Se agradece cualquier ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

para las img svg en el html no se puede usar las {{}}
debes usar el [src] = ""

<img [src]="qrImage" alt='QR Code' width='350' height='350'>

Comment: Dale formato a tu código con triples comillas invertidas (```) una línea antes y una después de la misma. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.